# Need to convert column values of data frame into separate columns and populate count values for each cell using panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have a dataframe

```
data_frame = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'name':["A","B","C","A","B","A"], 'date':["15/03/2019","16/03/2019","15/03/2019","16/03/2019","16/03/2019","16/03/2019"], "conducted":[1,1,1,1,1,1],"present":[1,1,1,1,1,0]})`
```

---

Result

[image: DataSet]

---

I need to convert data frame into

[image: ResultDataSet]

---

I have tried this so far,

1. Find unique values for date and names

```
date_unique_list = data_frame.date.unique()
name_unique_list = data_frame.name.unique()
```

Result :

```
array(['15/03/2019', '16/03/2019'], dtype=object)
array(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype=object)
```

2. create data frame with date columns and name row headers.

```
data_frame_dummies = pd.get_dummies(date_unique_list,prefix="",prefix_sep="")
data_frame_dummies = pd.DataFrame(data_frame_dummies, columns = date_unique_list, index=name_unique_list)
```

Result :

```
    15/03/2019  16/03/2019
A   NaN           NaN
B   NaN           NaN
C   NaN           NaN
```

3. Update count of presence for each student date wise.

-> I don't seem to be finding a way for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the values inside the table are a `sum()` of `conducted`.

You can use `pandas` `pivot_table()`, and fill missing values with zeros `fillna(0.0)` e.g.:

```
import numpy as np
table = pd.pivot_table(data_frame, values=['conducted'], index=['name'], columns=['date'], aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0.0)
```

**EDIT**

With counted `present` values:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(data_frame, values=['present'], index=['name'], columns=['date'], aggfunc='count').fillna(0.0)
```

[image]

Comment: Values inside should count of present.

Comment: Yup, Thanks :)  I was wondering how may I access it's individual cell values in loop ?

Comment: You're wellcome :-). It depends what you want to loop over. You can e.g. access the "rows" with `table.loc['A']` or make a list of the values inside the column `A` with `[v for v in table.loc['A']]`